# Retrieving the selected values from Bootstrap dual list in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am building a web app using .NET core 2.1. In one of the views there are multiple select lists, each contains thousands of items for the user to choose from so I decided to use bootstrap dual list (https://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/). I have 2 issues with this setup:
1- When I hit the submit button, the model coming to the post action method does not contain the items selected by the user in the dual lists (The items in the right hand side of the list)
2- I need to save the items selected by the user so he can have the same list each time he logs in the app (The original not selected list is populated from the database with all the items shown regardless to the user selections from last time he used the app)
Here is my code:

ViewModel.cs:

```
public ViewModel() 
{
    TradeList = new List<DimTrade>();
    LocationList = new List<DimLocation>();
}
public List<DimTrade> TradeList { get; set; }
public List<DimLocation> LocationList { get; set; }
```

cshtml:

```
<div class="col-8">
    <select id="ddlTrade" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.TradeList" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.TradeList, "TradeKey", "Name"))"
            placeholder="Please select" multiple="multiple" name="TradeList"></select>
</div>

<div class="col-8">
    <select id="ddlLocation" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.LocationList" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.LocationList, "LocationKey", "Name"))"
            placeholder="Please select" multiple="multiple" name="LocationList"></select>
</div>
<scaript>
    $('[name=TradeList]').bootstrapDualListbox();
    $('[name=LocationList]').bootstrapDualListbox();
</script>
```

Post action method:

```
public IActionResult Edit(ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         // Process the model
    }
    return View(model);
```

The problem is that the TradeList and LoactionList objects are always null.

I appreciate your help with both issues

Comment: Did you try looking into the raw request query / post params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- When I hit the submit button, the model coming to the post action method does not contain the items selected by the user in the dual lists (The items in the right hand side of the list)

As @Charles mentioned, if you check the request, you would find only the selected vlaue of dropdown was sent via form data, like below.

[image]

To get selected value(s) of **ddlTrade** and **ddlLocation**, you can try to modiofy and inclue properties for selected values in your view model class, like below.

```
public List<DimTrade> TradeList { get; set; }
public List<DimLocation> LocationList { get; set; }

public List<string> SelectedTradeKeyList { get; set; }
public List<string> SelectedLocationKeyList { get; set; }
```

Then modify the html and js code of these two dropdowns as below.

```
<div class="col-8">
    <select id="ddlTrade" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.SelectedTradeKeyList" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.TradeList, "TradeKey", "Name"))"
            placeholder="Please select" multiple="multiple"></select>
</div>

<div class="col-8">
    <select id="ddlLocation" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.SelectedLocationKeyList" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.LocationList, "LocationKey", "Name"))"
            placeholder="Please select" multiple="multiple"></select>
</div>

$('#ddlTrade').bootstrapDualListbox();
$('#ddlLocation').bootstrapDualListbox();
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Note: you can also try another apporach to achieve your requirement. For example, you can dynamically generate form data based on parameter your controller action expected, then submit it using jQuery etc.

> 2- I need to save the items selected by the user so he can have the same list each time he logs in the app

You can try to maintain user selected options in browser web storage, so that you can perform additional js code logic to set selected options for dropdown(s).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Thanks, the answer provided completely solved the first issue. For the second issue, I am looking for a solution where I feed the list with the items stored in the database.

Comment: Here is the answer that worked for me thanks @Xing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305189/populating-bootstrap-dual-list-boxes-with-pre-selected-items

Answer (score 2):

You could use jquery to get all selected options' value and text , then pass them to edit action:

```
<div class="col-8">
    <select id="ddlTrade" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.TradeList" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.TradeList, "TradeKey", "Name"))"
            placeholder="Please select" multiple="multiple" name="TradeList"></select>
</div>
<div class="col-8">
    <select id="ddlLocation" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.LocationList" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.LocationList, "LocationKey", "Name"))"
            placeholder="Please select" multiple="multiple" name="LocationList"></select>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="submit" id="showValue" />
</div>
<script>
    $('[name=TradeList]').bootstrapDualListbox();
    $('[name=LocationList]').bootstrapDualListbox();
</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#showValue").click(function () {
            var TradeList = [];
            var LocationList = [];
            $("[id*=-selected-list_TradeList] option").each(function () {
                var Trade = {
                    TradeKey: $(this).val(),
                    Name: $(this).text()
                };
                TradeList.push(Trade);
            });
            $("[id*=-selected-list_LocationList] option").each(function () {
                var Location = {
                    LocationKey: $(this).val(),
                    Name: $(this).text()
                };
                LocationList.push(Location);
            });
            var model = {
                TradeList: TradeList,
                LocationList: LocationList
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/DualListbox/Edit',
                data: model,
                success: function (data) {
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Result:
[image]